# MLE of Poisson Variable

Tags: statistics, estimation

Consider a random sample of size $n$ from a Poisson distribution with mean $\mu$. Let $\theta=P(X=0)$. Find the MLE of $\theta$ and show that it is a consistent estimator.

--We have $\theta=P(X=0)=e^{-\mu}$. To find the MLE, I took the log likelihood, $\ell(\mu,\mathbf{x})=-n\mu$, which has a derivative $-n$ with respect to $\mu$. Therefore the MLE would be $0$. Is this calculation correct? It seems too simple...

Comment: Let us see: In your derivation, you got a likelihood function _which do not depend on the data $X$_, that should be an indicator that your solution is wrong! (You get an estimator, which do not depend on data!, and that cant possibly be consistent or correct.) Just write the ordinary poisson likelihood as a function of the ne parameter $\mu$, and begin anew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take the joint likelihood of the $n$ samples. If $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are the samples you write $$\log P(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)=\log\prod P(X=X_i)\\=\sum\log P(X=X_i)\\=\sum (X_i\log\lambda -\lambda-\log(X_i!)).$$ To find the MLE of $\theta$ you write the above expression in terms of $\theta$ and the maximizer with respect to $\theta$ would be the desired MLE.

Comment: To write this in terms of $\theta=e^{-\lambda}$, would it be easier to use the ordinary likelihood function rather than the log likelihood? That way, we have $P(X_{1},\dots,X_{n})=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{x_{i}}}{x_{i}!}=\frac{e^{-n\lambda}\lambda^{\sum x_{i}}}{\sum x_{i}!}=\frac{\theta^{-n}\lambda^{\sum x_{i}}}{\sum x_{i}!}$. Then we could take the log of this. Would that work in yielding an MLE of $\theta$?

Comment: Usually, taking derivative from the log likelihood function is simpler. By the way, you should write every $\lambda$ in terms of $\theta$. In this example, since $\theta = e^{-\lambda}$ is a one-to-one mapping, you can simply maximize with respect to $\lambda$ and then find the corresponding $\theta$.